# Numpy where functionality for Julia code?

Tags: python, numpy, julia, where-clause, array-broadcasting

I read the answer to ["What is Julia equivalent of numpy's where function?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56137218/what-is-julia-equivalent-of-numpys-where-function), but do not yet see how the answer (ifelse) gives the user all the functionality of numpy.where. I have posted example code below:

```
    A = [0.0 0.9 0.0 0.99 0.0]

    a = 1:length(A)

    #-v- produces [0 1.0 0 1.0 0] as expected, but how to get the index values?
    b = ifelse.(A .- 1.0 .> -1.0, 1.0, 0 )
    #-^- how to get the array [0.9 0.99]? How to remove all zeros from an array?
```

Any workarounds other than using for loops would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not loops? Loops are fast

Comment: There's no point to using `where` for this even in NumPy. NumPy supports logical indexing, just like Julia.

Comment: Does `numpy.where` really support what you are asking for? I doesn't look like it from the docs. Can you show a numpy example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Potentially avoiding allocating the masking array would be faster, so 
`filter(x -> x>0,  A)`

Answer (score 10):

I guess you're looking for the functionality of `np.where(cond)`?  That's simply [`findall(A .> 0)`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.findall-Tuple%7BAny%7D).

To get the array `[0.9, 0.99]`, I'd use [logical indexing](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Logical-indexing-1): `A[A .> 0]`.